# What exactly happens if you use `var` on an already initialized variable

Tags: javascript

I'm just wondering what exactly happens (internally) if you try to initialize a variable multiple times.

For example:

```
var x = -5;

if(x < 0) {
    var x = 5;
}
```

I understand that the final result will be `x = 5` but will this cause the browser to destroy the variable and re-initiate it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth — Not a duplicate. That discusses variables in different functions. This question is about the use of `var` multiple times in the same function.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth That's not the same. The first initiation is tied to window, the second one is tied in the function.

Comment: Two bites and the cherry—the question in the subject is different to the question in the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[When a function is abeout to be executed, all variable and function declarations are evaluated.](http://es5.github.io/#x10.5) This is the step for the variable declarations:

> 8. For each *VariableDeclaration* and *VariableDeclarationNoIn d* in *code*, in source text order do
>
> a. Let *dn* be the *Identifier* in *d*.
>
> b. Let *varAlreadyDeclared* be the result of calling *env*’s HasBinding concrete method passing *dn* as the argument.
>
> c. If *varAlreadyDeclared* is **false**, then
>       i. Call *env*’s CreateMutableBinding concrete method passing *dn* and *configurableBindings* as the arguments.
>       ii. Call *env*’s *SetMutableBinding* concrete method passing *dn*, **undefined**, and *strict* as the arguments.

That's it, there is no "else" clause for `varAlreadyDeclared` being `true`. Nothing happens when the variable was already declared.

Answer (score 5):

No.

`var` gets hoisted anyway, so it doesn't matter where it appears in the function.

Comment: I'm just curious, does ECMA standard say anything about double declaration?

Comment: [ish](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.5). It says to only do something if it hasn't been declared already.